# Mockito mock creation inside mock creation

Tags: mockito, kotlin

The error I get is `org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException`, with one of the possible reasons "you are stubbing the behaviour of another mock inside before 'thenReturn' instruction if completed".

```
    val mockHttpHandlerContext = mock<HttpHandlerContext>().let {
        whenever(it.request).thenReturn(mock<HttpRequest>().let {
            whenever(it.queryParameters).thenReturn(mapOf(
                    "itype" to listOf("msisdn"),
                    "uid" to listOf(inputMsisdn)
            ))
            it
        })
        whenever(it.scope()).thenReturn(ProcessingScope.of(Timings("test", 1000L)))
        it
    }
```

Is the only solution to get rid of nested mock creation? It would really make code harder to understand, maybe there is a known workaround?

The code snippet is Kotlin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the naming, I assume you're using [nhaarman/Mockito-Kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin)?

Mockito is stateful, you must create mocks sequentially, but there are some ways of flipping the order of evaluation. For example,

```
val mockHttpHandlerContext2 = mock<HttpHandlerContext>() {
    mock<HttpRequest>() {
        on { queryParameters }.thenReturn(mapOf(
                "itype" to listOf("msisdn"),
                "uid" to listOf(inputMsisdn)
        ))
    }.let { on { request }.thenReturn(it) }
    on { scope() }.thenReturn(ProcessingScope.of(Timings("test", 1000L)))
}
```

I'm taking advantage of the `mock()` overload with a `KStubbing<T>` receiver, but the important bit is creating the inner mock first before using `.let` to set it on the stub.

Another option would be to use `.thenAnswer` to defer creation of the inner mock until the time when stubbed method is called.

```
val mockHttpHandlerContext = mock<HttpHandlerContext>() {
    on { request }.thenAnswer {
        mock<HttpRequest>() {
            on { queryParameters }.thenReturn(mapOf(
                    "itype" to listOf("msisdn"),
                    "uid" to listOf(inputMsisdn)
            ))
        }
    }
    on { scope() }.thenReturn((ProcessingScope.of(Timings("test", 1000L)))
}
```

Note that this will create a new mock every time the stubbed method is called. It might not be desirable in some situations, such as if you want to perform verification on the inner mock.